# Trying to make a dataframe by imposing condition on a column of another datarframe

Tags: python, while-loop

I was making two dataframes. The second dataframe was creadted by imposing condition on the one of the columns of the first dataframes. The first dataframe was generated successfully but the second dataframe came out empty. Both of the dataframes were written on a text file. I wend throught the text file with first dataframe and the rows that I was looking for were present.

I used nested while loop where both inner and outer loops are forwarded by 0.1 that generates the first dataframe of 885482 rows. The code works if the loops are forwarded by 0.5 but in this case I would loost some datapoints.

Please help me find the bug. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import os

# insert your folder location inside the qouations
wdir = r'C:\Users\abdul\Documents\Research\CdTe\a-SiC_H and a-SiC_B_H on CdTe'  # location of working dircetory.
os.chdir(wdir)   # changing directory so that python knows which folder to work in and where to save the text file (generated data file) 

full_data_file = open('Z_data_full_data.txt', 'w')    # initiating text file that will have all data rows
Selected_rows_data_file = open('Z_data_selected_data.txt', 'w')   # initiating text file that will have selected data rows

H2 = 100.00 # sccm   # fixed value

# initiating list to be appended by data from while loops
CH4_lst = []   
SiH4_lst = []
H2_lst = []
Z_lst = []
RH_lst = []

# initiating variables before while loops
CH4 = 1     # sccm
while CH4 <= 95:
  SiH4 = 1    # scmm
  while SiH4 <= 95:
    Z_ratio = CH4 / (SiH4 + CH4)
    RH = H2 / (CH4 + SiH4)
        
    CH4_lst.append(CH4)
    SiH4_lst.append(SiH4)
    H2_lst.append(H2)
    Z_lst.append(Z_ratio)
    RH_lst.append(RH)

    # nested loop increment 
    SiH4 += 0.10   # if this is set at >0.5 then program works the way i want, but i want to work with 0.1
  # outer loop increment  
  CH4 += 0.10    # if this is set at >0.5 then program works the way i want, but i want to work with 0.1

# making dataframes (full_data_file) from multiple lists and setting column name 
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(CH4_lst, SiH4_lst, H2_lst, RH_lst, Z_lst)), 
                 columns = ['CH4_flowrate(sccm)', 'SiH4_flowrate(sccm)', 'H2_flowrate(sccm)', 'RH=[H2]/([CH4]+[SiH4])', 'Z=CH4/([CH4]+[SiH4])']) 

# making dataframe (Selected_rows_data_file) with selected rows 
selecting_rows = df_1['RH=[H2]/([CH4]+[SiH4])'].values == 10    # this condition works if the while loop increments are set at >0.5

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df_1[selecting_rows])

# writing dataframe (full_data_file) to a text file 
full_data_file.write(df_1.to_string(justify='right', index=False))  # data can be seen in the text 

# writing dataframe (Selected_rows_data_file) to a text file 
Selected_rows_data_file.write(df_2.to_string(justify='right', index=False))   # here is the problelm, i dont see any see data it it. 

full_data_file.close()  # closing text file from in the code. it shuold be done otherwise python will keep working on the text file 
Selected_rows_data_file.close() # closing text file from in the code. it shuold be done otherwise python will keep working on the text file

os.startfile('{}\\Z_data_full_data.txt'.format(wdir), 'open')   # opening the text file after writing in it. text file will open 
os.startfile('{}\\Z_data_selected_data.txt'.format(wdir), 'open')  # opening the text file after writing in it. text file will open
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I have done that part already. This is a go-to method for debugging , right? I will do that again to see if I miss anythign. But the point is if you set loops increment 0.5 then the code works as I mentioned and in this case I will loose some datapoint.